# Setting up SSL on a load balancer

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https, load-balancing

I currently have a load balancer with the NGINX setup:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.0.20;
    server 192.168.0.30;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    ...
}
```

and on the clusters (`192.168.0.20`,`192.168.0.30`) the NGINX setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/website.co/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name website.co www.website.co;

    include /etc/nginx/commonStuff.conf; #php settings etc..
}
```

This works perfectly for http connections.

---

I am now wanting to set the server to work with a https connection for one domain (`website.co`). So I thought of adding this to the load balancers NGINX settings:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.co www.website.co;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /NAS/ssl/cert_chain_website.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /NAS/ssl/website.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

and change the listening port on the clusters NGINX settings to `443` and keep everything else the same.

---

Now if I connect to `http://website.co` or infact anyother virtual domain on my server it returns

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> the plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

So this means an issue with the redirect.

---

If I connect to `https://website.co` it returns:

> **404 Not Found**

---

### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `ssl on` and use `http:` in `proxy_pass`

Comment: @AlexeyTen that works! I also want all `http` request to be redirected to `https` though!?

Comment: Add another server block. This question is asked so often…

Comment: I have done as I stated in the question...

Comment: For forcing all requests for a domain to be HTTPS, this post might provide more pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34644304/4072843

Comment: I am wanting the load balancer to connect through ssl and then the clusters to be through http in the backend! So that my servers have https protocol